# Managing permissions in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: permissions

i'm new to sharepoint, so don't judje me strictly. I have a site where i need to set some permissions, but the issue is that for some libraries and lists I need to set some ***"access denied"*** permision or at least disable ability to download or open documents in library for some group, and I don't know how to do it. I looked at limited access, but it still alows to open documents in library ans i'm stuck. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [Break permission inheritance on a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM10) and than assign unique permissions only to users/groups that will have to read/edit documents in these libraries. Check [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM4) for more details about adding permissions.

Once permissions are revoked these users will not see these libraries and documents stored there.

Comment: I did as you said and removed permission for that group in librabrary but I'm still able to access it content.

Comment: you said you were new to SP, so bare with the question: did you check with a user that should not have access?

Comment: I have all usernames and passwords so i just logged in and was able to access library and download document

Comment: User or Group may also be members of a different group and this might be a problem too...

Comment: I checked out and it turns out that administrator created new users for customers, but left old and they where in group so changing permisions for old, has no efect for new. Big thanks for pointing me this.